# undefined reference to `NgramTree...'

Tags: c++

My code gives:

```
undefined reference to `NgramTree::generateTree(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

error and I dont understand why.

Here is a sample of my code.

**NgramTree.cpp**

```
#include "NgramTree.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void generateTree(string fileName, int n)
{
    string line;
    string ngram;
    bool isWord = 1;
    bool firstTime = 1;

    ifstream myFile(fileName);

    if (!myFile.is_open())
        return;
...
```

**NgramTree.h**

```
#include <string>
class NgramTree {
    public :

        NgramTree (){ };
        ~NgramTree(){ };

        void addNgram (std::string ngram );
        int getTotalNgramCount ();
        void printNgramFrequencies ();
        bool isComplete ();
        bool isFull ();
        void generateTree(std::string fileName, int n);
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "NgramTree.h"

using namespace std;

    int main(){

        NgramTree tree;
        tree.generateTree("example.txt", 3);

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: More of a typo: `void generateTree(string fileName, int n)` needs to be added to the class. -> `void NgramTree ::generateTree(string fileName, int n)`. Without the scope it's a free function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class name in the cpp file. Write this, so that the compiler knows which class the method belongs to:

```
void NgramTree::generateTree(string fileName, int n) {
    ...
```